# Create List of PopupMenuItems from firebase data

Tags: firebase, flutter, popupmenubutton

I have 3 cars docs in the Cars collection in my firebase cloudstore. I want to create a list of PopupMenuItems in my PopupMenuButon based on the number of cars in my Cars Collection. I also want the value of my PopupMenuItems to be the names of the cars in my Cars collection.I need help because I'm stuck and I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Hi Albert, you need to show us where you are stuck. Did you try any code? Can you already retrieve the items from Firebase, print them on screen? In short, you could use a streambuilder, use the snapshot.data from firebase, and make a for loop to return a list of PopupMenuItems, one for each item in your collection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.